# Handling missing NSUserDefault keys after app updates

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I've just got burned because an update to my iOS app went live on the App Store and unfortunately it crashes when using a new feature because of a bug in the way my code uses `NSUserDefaults`. My app uses `registerDefaults`, but the new feature tries to write to a key that doesn't exist after upgrading. It works fine if installing from scratch because the key gets created by `registerDefaults`.

To be specific, my app uses nested dictionaries, so before the update the preferences file has this structure:

```
<dict>
    <key>Alpha</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>Value</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Beta</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>Value</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Charlie</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>Value</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

—and after the update, key *Delta* is required:

```
<dict>
    <key>Alpha</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>Value</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Beta</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>Value</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Charlie</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>Value</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Delta</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>Value</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

My code is falling over when it tries to retrieve the dictionary for *Delta* from the user defaults in order to write some keys and values to it. For this scenario the dictionary is `nil` because after an update it's not in the preferences file.

What's the best practice way to handle this situation? Should I simply check to see if the dictionary for *Delta* is `nil` before attempting to write to it and create it if required, or is there a less belt and braces approach?

Comment: "the new feature tries to write to a key that doesn't exist after upgrading" : this should be no issue at all. if the key is not there, it is created. could you post your code or elaborate more on what you are actually doing?

Comment: Side note. Didn't you test a user upgrade of your app before submitting to Apple? Before you submit an update to Apple you must always test a clean install and you must test an upgrade from prior versions of your app. And these must all be done with clean builds to be sure old files are left around by mistake.

Comment: Show your code for registering defaults and dealing with the `Delta` key.

Comment: @rmaddy I must admit that I didn't test the user update scenario, only the clean install. That was stupid, so I've learned a valuable lesson there.

Comment: Actually... I think my answer down below describes your problem quite well (and before you posted the code). That really is the best solution for this type of situation. Your going to have to do some kind of check based on Version number for the presence of the Delta key in your Dict. If its not there you are going to have to build a new one with the old values add delta and then replace the old with the new. Don't forget, what you get out from the NSUserPrefs is an NSDict... and is NOT mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a simple test with your data:

1. add a defaults.plist file to an empty project;
2. set  defaults.plist to contain Alpha/Beta/Charlie keys (as per your example);
3. use the following code at appDidFinishLaunching time:

   ```
   NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"defaults" ofType:@"plist"];
   NSDictionary* factoryPrefs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:factoryPrefs];
   NSLog(@"Delta Key: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Delta"]);

   //-- store some user custom values
   NSLog(@"Charlie Key %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Charlie"]);
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"test" forKey:@"Charlie"];
   NSLog(@"Charlie Key %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Charlie"]);
   ```
4. run the app;

Outcome was:

```
2013-02-23 17:59:10.795 JigSaw[14747:c07] Delta Key (null)
2013-02-23 17:59:10.797 JigSaw[14747:c07] Charlie Key {
    Key = Value;
}
2013-02-23 17:59:10.797 JigSaw[14747:c07] Charlie Key test
```

Then, I changed the content of defaults.plist by adding the Delta key (again, as per your example), and built/ran the app again (without deleting it from the device, of course).

Outcome was:

```
2013-02-23 18:00:37.840 JigSaw[15040:c07] Delta Key {
    Key = Value;
}
2013-02-23 18:00:37.842 JigSaw[15040:c07] Charlie Key test
2013-02-23 18:00:37.842 JigSaw[15040:c07] Charlie Key test
```

So, it seems that `registerDefaults` will correctly handle any newly added key when used like in the example above.

I tend to think that either you are using `registerDefaults` incorrectly, or you are doing something elsewhere that is the cause of the crash.

At a more general level, apart from testing the app update scenario (which is trivial to suggest after the fact, and we all learned it the hard way, one way or another), the good practice for me would me ensuring that your app does not crash even in the presence of wrong or unforeseen input.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I follow to avoid these situations is as follows:

In my ApplicationDelegate `+(void)initialize` method I set up the keys and their defaults like so to ensure nothing attempts to touch the defaults before they are setup:

```
+(void)initialize
{
    NSDictionary *factoryPrefs = @{MyNewPrefKey:@"ANewPrefKeyDefaultValue"};
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:factoryPrefs];
userSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Next, and immediately after this I have a block of code that based on current version, starts checking for the existence of previous values that imply a user was upgrading (not new). In that case I'm going to have to migrate/update the prefs.

For example, sometimes keys have to be altered or values inserted like if you stored an NSDictionary object with value a, b, c in it in some previous version, but now in this Ver. your depending on (and assuming) a 'd' value is also in there.

In that case `registerDefaults` is NOT going to help because as you noted the value was previously created. So YOU have to manually check if 'd' is in there and if NOT insert it with along with the default value. This is sort of the CoreData migration equivalent for Prefs :)

That is what I do. I do it religiously. I check it EVERY release, because... I was burnt, just like you previously by NOT doing it. And then we all know what happens next, you get a serious 1 star a.. whooping in the App Store.